# Doctrine DQL LEFT JOIN set difference

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, left-join, dql

I have the following SQL query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.id
    FROM User u
    LEFT JOIN usergroup_user ug1 ON u.id = ug1.user_id
    LEFT JOIN usergroup_user ug2 ON ug1.user_id = ug2.user_id AND ug2.usergroup_id = :groupid
    WHERE ug2.usergroup_id IS NULL
```

What this does is return all the users that are not in usergroup :groupid. If the users have records for other groups in addition to the excluded group, I don't want those either.

The SQL query works, but is there a way to write this query in DQL, Doctrine for Symfony2?

I have tried this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.id
    FROM AcmeDemoBundle:User u
    LEFT JOIN u.groups ug1
    LEFT JOIN u.groups ug2 WITH ug1 = ug2 AND ug2 = :groupid
    WHERE ug2 IS NULL
```

but it doesn't work. The DQL statement is translated into the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT DISTINCT u0_.id AS id0
    FROM User u0_
    LEFT JOIN usergroup_user u2_ ON u0_.id = u2_.user_id
    LEFT JOIN UserGroup u1_ ON u1_.id = u2_.usergroup_id
    LEFT JOIN usergroup_user u4_ ON u0_.id = u4_.user_id
    LEFT JOIN UserGroup u3_ ON u3_.id = u4_.usergroup_id AND (u1_.id = u3_.id AND u3_.id = :groupid)
    WHERE u3_.id IS NULL
```

That's obviously not good, because it straddles the join tables and messes up the sets.

In math terms, using sets, I'm doing this: result = A\B (element that are in A but not in B), with A = "all the users", and B = "all the users in group :groupid".

Is what I want to do possible using DQL, or should I just use SQL for this case? Can it be done without turning the join tables into entities of their own?

**Test data**

ORM schema:

- Resources/config/doctrine/User.orm.yml

  ```
  Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\User:
    type: entity
    table: null
    fields:
      id:
        type: integer
        id: true
        generator:
          strategy: AUTO
    manyToMany:
      groups:
        targetEntity: UserGroup
        mappedBy: users
  ```
- Resources/config/doctrine/UserGroup.orm.yml

  ```
  Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\UserGroup:
    type: entity
    table: null
    fields:
      id:
        type: integer
        id: true
        generator:
          strategy: AUTO
    manyToMany:
      users:
        targetEntity: User
        inversedBy: groups
  ```

SQL data:

```
INSERT INTO `User` VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4);
INSERT INTO `UserGroup` VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4);
INSERT INTO `usergroup_user` VALUES (1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(2,2),(3,4);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found the answer just after I posted, in a "related" link in the sidebar, which mentioned `MEMBER OF` in a possibly non-related context.

My DQL now looks like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.id
    FROM AcmeDemoBundle:User u
    WHERE :group NOT MEMBER OF u.groups
```

Which translates to this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT u0_.id AS id0
    FROM User u0_
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM usergroup_user u1_
        INNER JOIN UserGroup u2_ ON u1_.usergroup_id = u2_.id
        WHERE u1_.user_id = u0_.id AND u2_.id = :group
    )
```

It looks like it's doing the right thing too.

This is one of those answers that one finds by chance, just *after* posting to StackOverflow after not finding anything by searching Google and StackOverflow for a few days :)

**Fun Fact**: You can't run this DQL in Symfony2's ./app/console with doctrine:query:dql - at least it gives me an error when I try replacing :group with an ID.